# Dynamically create UI elements via Controller and bind them to a specific properties in Model

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5, sap-fiori, two-way-binding

I've been trying to add dynamic content to my dialog based on specific object in my JSONmodel, which is an array of objects.

My model has the following structure, I've set it like this(dummy data):

**Note**: *I have multiple models active in this controller's view, each of which has its own model data.*

```
this.setData( emp: [
                    {
                        col1: "1.4",
                        col2: "2.0",
                        col3: "3.1"
                    },
                    {
                        col1: "4.1",
                        col2: "5.3",
                        col3: "6.5"
                    }
                ]);
```

So I've set the model data successfully and now I am able to access it via:

```
var modelData= this.oView.getModel("myModel").oData;
```

What I want now is to dynamically create `sap.m.Dialog` and dynamically fill it with multiple `sap.m.Input` elements which have values based on a single object from my model:

```
var getDialogContent = function(modelData){         
            var arr = [];
            var keys = Object.keys(modelData[0]); // property names. I hard-coded first obj for test.
            // I want to use these properties and bind a new input on dialog for each property.

            jQuery.each(keys, function(i, key) {

// 'myModel>/emp/0/'+key is a supposed full path to property...
//  according to this link: 
//  https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.36.6/docs/guide/91f0ed206f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html

                    newInput.bindProperty("value", 'myModel>/emp/0/' + key); //key is col1 the first time
                    newInput.setProperty("description", key);
                    newInput.setProperty("type", sap.m.InputType.Number);
                    arr.push(newInput); 
            });
            return arr;
        };
```

I call getDialogContent() in the content property of the dialog to set its content.

Now, everything works save for the binding `newInput.bindProperty("value", 'myModel>/emp/0/' + key);`, the input fields that are displayed are just empty and show no sign of binding, also `newInput.getBindingContext("myModel");` returns undefined.

```
        var dialog = new sap.m.Dialog({
            title: 'Dynamic dialog: ',
            type: 'Message',
            content: getDialogContent(modelData),
            buttons: new sap.m.Button({
                text: 'Cancel',
                press: function () {                    
                    dialog.close();
                }
            }),
            afterClose: function() {
                dialog.destroy();
            }
        });
```

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong here and why can't I bind my property to the input element? I basically just want to bind values of my dynamic input fields to arbitrary object from object array in my JSON Model. Any suggestion is welcome.

Edit(Solution):
On the var `keys = Object.keys(modelData[0]);` line I replaced `modelData[0]` with `modelData["emp"][0]` as I was accessing specific object form JSONModel. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you [add the dialog to the dependents of your view](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/4da72985139b4b83b5f1c1e0c0d2ed5a)? When I remove that step in our app, the result is exactly as you described: The fields are empty and `getBindingContext()` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Hey Johann. Are you sure you are talking about Dialog, and not Fragment? Because I haven't seen example of adding Dialog to view's dependencies.
But what strikes me as interesting in your link is this sentence:
"Dialogs are special, because they open on top of the regular app content and thus do not belong to a specific view."
Does that mean dialog is unable to access view's binding context? I'm unable to answer that now as I'm at home.. I'll check back tomorrow at work. :)

Comment: Hey Johann I got it to work. I changed this line:
var keys = Object.keys(modelData[0]) 
to:
var keys = Object.keys(modelData["emp"][0])
and used path just like before:
newInput.bindProperty("value", 'troskoviModel>/emp/0/' + key)

Yesterday I've tried a million variations but I guess I missed this one. At first I added data directly without an "emp" identifier in my model object and it wouldn't work. So I added "'myModel>/emp/0/' + key" so I could use absolute path like in documentation suggests. But I guess modelData["emp"][0] was what was missing. Thanks

Comment: By the way I never added dialog to dependencies, I just dynamically created it like any other input element.

Comment: Oh my God, I just realized that with "Did you add the dialog to the dependents of your view?" you actually meant this.getView().addDependent(dialog)...

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way to implement a dialog in a reusable manner is the one described in [this link](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.m.Dialog/sample/sap.m.sample.Dialog). You have to add the dialog as dependent to the "parent" view in order to retrieve the models set on that view.

```
onDialogOpen: function () {
            if (!this.oDialog) {
                this.oDialog =  new sap.m.Dialog({
                   title: 'Dynamic dialog: ',
                   type: 'Message',
                   content: getDialogContent(modelData),
                   buttons: new sap.m.Button({
                      text: 'Cancel',
                      press: function () {                    
                        this.oDialog.close();
                      }.bind(this)
                   }),
                   afterClose: function() {
                     this.oDialog.destroy();
                   }.bind(this)
               });            
               //to get access to the view models
               this.getView().addDependent(this.oDialog);
            }    
            this.oDialog.open();
        },
```

Comment: Hey I was tinkering with this for a bit and from what I gather, your code example is different from mine only by `.bind(this)` after `afterClose` event property. What does `.bind(this)` actually do? 
Anyway I got it to work, I explained in the reply to Johann's comment.
I also added a change event on input field:

`var newInput = new sap.m.Input({ change: this.onInputChanged }) ` 

But I am unable to pass any args to onInputChanged function, as when I add an argument inside brackets, `this.onInputChanged(arg)`, func is immediately invoked. Know what's the proper way to pass args? Thanks!

Comment: My code is different from yours also because I added this two fundamental lines
 (1)//to get access to the view models(2)
this.getView().addDependent(this.oDialog);

What you are asking is a basic javascript question.... and that's why .bind() was invented. I'm sure you can google it and find tons of information about it.

Comment: Sorry I just realized I hadn't posted all of my controller code. But I had added `this.getView().addDependent(this.oDialog)` already. I didn't have problem with that. Also, sorry for the stupid question, got careless for a second and forgot bind() is a pure js :)

What I wanted to ask though is do you perhaps know how can I pass custom parameters to change event of `newInput = new sap.m.Input({ change: this.onInputChanged })`? As it is now, my onInputChanged func only accepts parameter that is automatically passed as an object that triggered the event. I wanted to pass 'this' as well.

Comment: Never mind, I took a page from your book and added .bind(this) to `this.onInputChanged` in `sap.m.Input({ change: this.onInputChanged })`. Thanks